# How to count frequency of single word and also double word count from input text in python?

Tags: python, regex

Hello I want to count single word and double word count from input text in python .
Ex.

```
"what is your name ? what you want from me ?
 You know best way to earn money is Hardwork 
 what is your aim ?"
```

output:

```
sinle W.C. : 
what   3
 is    3
 your  2
you    2
```

and so on..

```
Double W.C. :
what is 2
is your 2
your name 1
what you 1
```

ans so on..
please post the way to do this ?
i use following code for the singl word count :

ws={}

for line in text:

```
for wrd in line:

    if wrd not in ws:

        ws[wrd]=1

    else:

        ws[wrd]+=1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: You mention Python. What did you try with Python to solve the problem?

Comment: yaaa i looking for solution with regex in python.and i had done single word count .

Comment: Please: Add to your question the code you tried to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter

s = "..."

words = s.split()
pairs = zip(words, words[1:])

single_words, double_words = Counter(words), Counter(pairs)
```

Output:

```
print "sinle W.C."
for word, count in sorted(single_words.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1]):
    print word, count

print "double W.C."
for pair, count in sorted(double_words.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1]):
    print pair, count
```

Comment: use just `split()`, And I guess just `zip(words,words[1:])` will work fine.

Comment: +1 you beat me to it, I would've posted the same solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import nltk
from nltk import bigrams
from nltk import trigrams

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tokens = [token.lower() for token in tokens if len(token) > 1]
bi_tokens = bigrams(tokens)

print [(item, tokens.count(item)) for item in sorted(set(tokens))]
print [(item, bi_tokens.count(item)) for item in sorted(set(bi_tokens))]
```

Answer (score 0):

this works. using defaultdict. python 2.6

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> string = "what is your name ? what you want from me ?\n
    You know best way to earn money is Hardwork\n what is your aim ?"
>>> l = string.split()
>>> for i in l:
    d[i]+=1

>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'me': 1, 'aim': 1, 'what': 3, 'from': 1, 'name': 1, 
    'You': 1, 'money': 1, 'is': 3, 'earn': 1, 'best': 1, 'Hardwork': 1, 'to': 1, 
    'way': 1, 'know': 1, 'want': 1, 'you': 1, 'your': 2, '?': 3})
>>> d2 = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in zip(l[:-1], l[1:]):
    d2[i]+=1

>>> d2
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('You', 'know'): 1, ('earn', 'money'): 1, 
    ('is', 'Hardwork'): 1, ('you', 'want'): 1, ('know', 'best'): 1, 
    ('what', 'is'): 2, ('your', 'name'): 1, ('from', 'me'): 1, 
    ('name', '?'): 1, ('?', 'You'): 1, ('?', 'what'): 1, ('to', 'earn'): 1, 
    ('aim', '?'): 1, ('way', 'to'): 1, ('Hardwork', 'what'): 1, 
    ('money', 'is'): 1, ('me', '?'): 1, ('what', 'you'): 1, ('best', 'way'): 1,
    ('want', 'from'): 1, ('is', 'your'): 2, ('your', 'aim'): 1})
>>>
```

Comment: `collections.defaultdict(int)` + increments = `collections.Counter` :)

Comment: @defuz yes, collections.Counter is 2.7+ i still have 2.6 ... like many people :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a few years old.  I wrote a little routine today to just count individual words from a word doc (docx).  I used docx2txt to get the text from the word document, and used my first regex expression ever to remove every character other than alpha, numeric or spaces, and switched all to uppercase.  I put this in because the question isn't answered.

Here is my little test routine in case it may help anyone.

```
mydoc = 'I:/flashdrive/pmw/pmw_py.docx'

words_all = {}

#####

import docx2txt

my_text = docx2txt.process(mydoc)
print(my_text)

my_text_org = my_text

import re

    #added this code for the double words

from collections import Counter

pairs = zip(words, words[1:])
pair_list = Counter(pairs)

print('before pair listing')

for pair, count in sorted(pair_list.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1]):
   #print (''.join('{} {}'.format(*pair)), count) #worked
   #print(' '.join(pair), '', count) #worked  
  
   new_pair = ("{} {}")
   my_pair = new_pair.format(pair[0],pair[1])
   print ((my_pair), ": ", count)
  
#end of added code

my_text = re.sub('[\W_]+', ' ', my_text.upper(), flags=re.UNICODE)
print(my_text)

words = my_text.split()

words_org = words #just in case I may need the original version later


for i in words:  
     if not i in words_all:
         words_all[i] = words.count(i)
          
  
for k,v in sorted(words_all.items()):
     print(k, v)

print("Number of items in word list: {}".format(len(words_all)))
```